# Android Manifest throwing up some errors

Tags: android, xml, manifest

Been reading many posts but not of them have helped, please bare in mind im new to android so the mistake may be obvious.

When examining the below code it states that the below are not allowed here.

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <!--
       The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
       Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
       location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
           The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
           (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
           Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
           You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key
           that is used to sign the APK for publishing.
           You can define the keys for the debug and
              release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tutorialspoint7.myapplication.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

These are the errors

```
Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'supportsRtl' in package 'android'
Error:(22, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:(43, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_maps').
Error:(25, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(22, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'supportsRtl' in package 'android'
Error:(43, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_maps').
Error:(25, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: the problem android:supportsRtl="true", do you need a right to left support ?

Comment: @MarkJames for RTL your app should target/minimum sdk version >17. For mipmap, check if you have image resource named by ic_launcher. For String, check if you have "title_activity_maps" in string.xml. For Style, check in style.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are using `android:supportsRtl="true"` then your targetSdk must be more then 17

Comment: @MarkJames Happy to help you :) :) :)

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-10' in: C:\Users\dawnlp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>

Answer (score 1):

as you are using android:supportsRtl="true" then your targetSdk must be 17